# How to Prove the $ {L}_{\infty} $ Ball Is Convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I want to prove that a ball for infinity norm is convex:

$$
B_\infty=\{x\in\mathbb R^n : \|x\|_\infty\le1\}
$$

I came up with this proof and appreciate it if someone can help to verify if this is correct:
\begin{align}
\|x\|_\infty&=\|(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\|_\infty\\&=\max_j|(1-\lambda)x|+\max_j|\lambda y|\\&=(1-\lambda)\max_j|x|+\lambda\max_j|y|\\&=(1-\lambda)+\lambda=1
\end{align}

P.S. This is a homework. Thanks!

Comment: The overall concept seems fine except the left-hand side of your equation. It should be replaced by the right-hand side of the first line. Also, you might want to put subscripts for components of $x$ and $y$, and replace many occurrences of $=$ with $\le$.

Comment: Note: A ball induced by _any_ norm is convex. This might be a tad easier to prove as you don't need to handle the maximum operator.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, Tunococ for the answer and Donkey_2009 for edition. I very much appreciate it. I would like to also make a correction, for the previous comment from @Tomas that a ball induced with any norm greater than 1 will be convex. This is because of the triangle inequalities will be reversed when p-norm is between 0 and 1. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @dracc What Tomas said was actually correct. When $p < 1$, the function you get is not a norm because, by definition, a *norm* has to satisfy the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x, y \in B_{\infty}$. Let $x_i$ and $y_i$ denote components of $x$ and $y$. Then for any $\lambda \in [0, 1]$,
\begin{align}
\|(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y\|_\infty
& = \max_i |(1 - \lambda)x_i + \lambda y_i| & & \text{by definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$}\\
& \le \max_i (1 - \lambda)|x_i| + \max_i \lambda|y_i| & & \text{by $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$} \\
& = (1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty + \lambda\|y\|_\infty & &
\text{by definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$}\\
& \le (1 - \lambda) + \lambda & &
\text{because $x \in B_\infty$ and $y \in B_\infty$}\\
& \le 1 \\
\therefore
(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y & \in B_{\infty}
\end{align}
Therefore, $B_{\infty}$ is convex.